# There are so many hotkeys in Vim - then how to choose a hotkey for your custom action?

Tags: vim

In Vim you often need to assign a key for your own custom action. But there are so many key combinations that already have an action mapped to them by default. How do you choose free key combinations when you need to assign you custom action to one?

In these situations I usually get lost and just assign my action to a custom command instead of a key, like :docoolstuff instead of a simple keypress.

And, by the way, do you often remap a default action to use a custom action on this key combination instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I bind custom command to <kbd>leader - {key}</kbd>. For example:

```
let mapleader = ','
nnoremap <leader>s       : so $MYVIMRC<CR>
nnoremap <leader>v       : tabe $MYVIMRC<CR>
```

I can press <kbd>,v</kbd> to open `vimrc` in a new tab.

Comment: Thanks for an idea, I'll be using it!

Comment: You can also use a double leader: `<leader><leader>s`, for example.

Comment: I do the same, but please note that by setting mapleader to ',', you already replace a (sometime useful) hotkey.

Answer (score 3):

I use <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> which work reliably enough for me. That's more keys than most would ever need. The higher keys are in my static setup, the lower ones are used for throw-away bindings.

Comment: I did that in the past, but they are a bit too far for my taste, and sometime they are taken by the system (either the WM or things like byobu).

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget alt-gr+key, which gives you a whole new set of characters to bind to. But mapleader, as suggested in the accepted answer, is the most standard practice.